# Is there a way to start foreground service without showing a notification for Android 8.0 and above versions?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, android-8.1-oreo

Working with Android 8.1 and above versions, I see that a notification is always displayed on the screen without being able to clear it. Just wanted to see if there is a way to run the service without displaying any notification?

http://android-devhelp.blogspot.com/2015/12/making-service-run-in-foreground.html says we can do it but sure how reliable this is.

Looking for any suggestion.

Comment: I think the documentation is pretty clear on background execution limits : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes - of note : While an app is in the foreground, it can create and run both foreground and background services freely.  Also worth noting in Android 9+ you require additional permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />` to start a foreground service.

Comment: Yeah I know just wanted to see any other way to do this. http://android-devhelp.blogspot.com/2015/12/making-service-run-in-foreground.html links says we can do it but not sure how reliable this is.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot run a foreground service without a persistent notification. This is both for power purposes and clarity for the user. The blog you reference is dated December 2015, which was shortly after Marshmallow (Android 6) was launched. The rules have gotten much more strict.

Depending on what you need to do in the background, you could use `JobScheduler` or the new `WorkManager`. Good luck!